# How to get 2 different classes in 1 model field in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I am working in a project, where I have to merge/combine different classes into one field.
I want to do it that way, because I have two different classes `ParkingArea1` and `ParkingArea2` and I want to have the choice from the Admin and WebInterface, to select any of these two areas from a single drop-down list, and ideally store them in another's model field.
These are my models:

```
class ParkingArea1(models.Model):
    zone_name = models.Charfield(max_length=255, unique=True)
    # some more unique fields below
    def __str__(self): return self.zone_name

class ParkingArea2(models.Model):
    area_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True, null=True, unique=True)
    # some more unique fields below
    def __str__(self): return self.area_name

class ChooseYourArea(models.Model):
    area = # here I want a field, which should be able to hold any of the above classes
    # some other stuff
```

How should I reform my models to achieve that?
NOTE: `ParkingArea1` and `ParkingArea2` are two actively used tables filled with data, so a change within these models wouldn't be optimal.

I researched a bit but couldn't find something to fit my case.
I understand that an abstract Base Class could be used for this case, but such a Base Class won't allow me to list all the areas that I want. Is there an obvious approach that I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing, was to create another class `ParkingAreas` with two fields, where each field can hold either `ParkingArea1` or `ParkingArea2`:

```
class ParkingAreas(models.Model):
  area1 = models.OneToOneField(ParkingArea1, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
  area2 = models.OneToOneField(ParkingArea2, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
  def __str__(self):
    if self.area1 is not None:
      return self.area1.area1
    else:
      return self.area2.area2

class ChooseYourArea(models.Model):
    area = models.ForeignKey(ParkingAreas, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    # some other stuff
```

Now I can get all parking areas in one place, even selectable with a drop-down menu, and store them in a ForeignKey field.
That way, when I need to access the areas, I can make some django queries and get what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can't if you want to use ForeignKeys. Both `ParkingArea1` and `ParkingArea2` have their own primary keys. Django won't know which table that foreign key belongs to. You need 2 fields.

There are ways around that but you need to ensure data consistency at the Django level, and the performance would be abysmal.